# Google map TypeError: a is null

Tags: javascript

I have to use google maps for my web application. The problem is I get an error that says TypeError: a is null. Here is how I call google map on window load:

```
var lat;
var long;
var map;

function geoloc() {//on window load get the user latitude and longitue and pass the values to   "successPosition" function if user allow the geolocation other wise call   "showError" function to gave static latitude and longitude.   


    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var optn = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 0,
            maximumAge: 0
        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successPosition, showError, optn);

    } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported in your browser');
    }
}

function successPosition(position) {  //get the latitude and longitude by geolocation function


    lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    long = position.coords.longitude;

    initialize(lat, long);//calling the initialize function
}

function initialize(lat, long) {   //initialize the map 

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    var mapOptions = {//maps options the zoom level and map center
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng

    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({//create the marker on the map
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}


function showError() {//pass the values to "initialize" function if the user dosn't allow the geolocation 

    initialize(31.5497, 74.3436);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', geoloc);//on window load calls the geoloc function to get the user latitude and longitud
```

When I run this on Firefox, Firebug tells me "TypeError: a is null".I don't have the slightest clue on how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it did create a Google Map. I am wondering if you properly included the Maps API JavaScript before you run your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ENTER-YOUR-UNIQUE-KEY-HERE">
</script>
```

Perhaps there is an error in another part of that site that is interfering?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&key=UNIQUE-KEY">
</script>
I include the script like this.
Before the functions mentioned above.But still having the same error.

Comment: Are you using your own API key?

Comment: Yes i am using my own API key

Comment: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);   The only way I was able to recreate issue was if there was no element with the id of 'googleMap'.  Make sure you have something like <div id="googleMap"></div>

Comment: Here is the div :

<div  style=" width:300px;height:170px;border:2px solid lightgrey;margin-bottom:8px;" id="googleMap">

Comment: I think you will need to update your question with all of your HTML and JavaScript before I can look into it any more.